# Android Eclipse Juno or ADT from Android developers site Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

Just wondering what is the difference between Eclipse JUNO, and ADT from Android developers site. Which is better to use on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop android application you should use Eclipse and ADT. Eclipse is a development environment for multiple programming languages. For example, with the Java Development Tools (JDT) it support Java development. [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) (Android Development Tools) is an another extension of Eclipse to support Android development. It adds a lot of functionality to Eclipse e.g. debuging tools which help you while coding and running android applications. However, to run Eclipse with ADT you still need the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

The [android developers site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is always a good start to develop android applications. You will find there everything you need.

Comment: Sry , maybe my question was not specific enough. I just want to know the difference between ECLIPSE JUNO and  ECLIPSE  that is in ADT BUNLDE witch you can donwload form ADROID DEVELOPERS SITE ,

Comment: Ah ok. I assume that the eclipse from the android developers site already includes the adt. Opposite to that, if you use a regular eclipse juno, then you have install adt by yourself. I think in your case using the eclipse from the android developers site is the right choice.